# Extjs 6 - Tree is truncating my <p>

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

So, I'm developing the help section of a site in Extjs 6+ / Modern. I'm running into a strange problem where - unless I manually insert linebreaks - any text in a width-limited paragraph (that's nested in a tree) simply disappears if it goes beyond the maximum width.

```
children:[
    {leaf:true, text:'<p style=\'width:320px; word-wrap: break-word; line-height:100%;\'>..</p>
```

I've tried multiple workarounds, including putting the < p > inside a width-limited < div >, but that doesn't help either.

[image: Text longer than 320 pixels is being lopped off]

For bureaucratic reasons I'm not supposed to touch the CSS, so I'm hoping there's something simple I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the solution.

```
{leaf:true, text:'<p style=\'width:320px; word-wrap: break-word; white-space:normal; line-height:100%;\'>..</p>
```

Adding **white-space:normal** rectifies the problem. I wasn't aware of the difference between white-space and line-spacing.

So, while it's an edge case, I'm going to leave this question up in case someone else runs into a similar issue.